# PHP Code for Drupal Views to Extract Field Value

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal Commerce and Views for an ecommerce site. I have a product displayed and I would like to be able to show related products that share the same reference field, i.e. All the products that share the same store (let's say stored under "store" field for each product).

My biggest problem is extracting a certain field value for the product I am currently viewing so I can then filter using the contextual filter in views.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you using this? Do you want to show the related products on the same page? Are you using views attachments or panels to bring this together?

Comment: Hi Quint, so let's say I have a page with url: http://legacyfair.com/furniture/1406832236...I would like to be able to pull the number at the end and search the database for the product and then from the same row grab the store field value. From there I should be fine as I am using Views and have the contextual filter set on store so once I return the store field value it should be pretty straightforward from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found that works:

```
$nodeid = explode('/', request_uri());
$a = commerce_product_load_by_sku($nodeid[2]);
$b = get_object_vars($a);
$c = $product['commerce_store'][und][0][entity];
$d = get_object_vars($c);
$product2 = $d[store_id]; 
return $product2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to extract specific field value.

e.g. if you want to extract field value in node template you can print out $node variable in node.tpl.php like this:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($node);
print "<pre>";
exit();
```

in this way you will find all fields and their values in $node object.

Also you can load any node using [node_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7) anywhere you want (e.g. in your module or in your theme or wherever) if you know node id (nid).

One of the ways to get nid is to fetch it using [arg()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) like this:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load($nid);
}
```

Another good way to fetch whole node with it's fields and values is [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) - this will return the object associated with the page currently shown. If the code is executed when Drupal is showing the page example.com/node/1, then menu_get_object() will return the node object for the node with node ID equal to 1; if the page being shown is example.com/user/1, then menu_get_object('user') will return the user object for the user with user ID equal to 1. [source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/6676)

Hope this information will be helpful.